# Why doesn't the type checker return an error with this indexable type?

Tags: typescript

I'm following the Microsoft Typescript Handbook and on the [indexable types chapter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) I was fiddling around with the code to understand it better. I ended up with this piece of code and don't know why it doesn't return an error:

```
interface NumberDictionary {
  [index: number]: number;
  length: number;
  name: number;
}

// 'x' is not a number, 's' is not a number
let foo: NumberDictionary = { x: 's', length: 2, name: 3 };
```

However, when I remove the first line in the interface, it does throw an error that x is not in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

That's because by declaring an index type you are saying something along the lines of: "the concrete implementation will ensure that you can do `obj[42]` and get back a `number`".

It doesn't matter that the other properties are not of that type.

With that declaration, `length` and `name` *must* be numbers, but the other ones are not checked.
In fact, I would say that the most potentially surprising thing of your snippet is that `x` is allowed at all.
Without the index declaration the structure of `foo` is properly enforced as we would expect from TS, and `x` is not allowed. With the index, it doesn't seem to complain. Odd.

My guess is that adding an index interface *relaxes* the typecheck to accommodate the double syntax `obj["bar"]` and `obj.bar`, which of course is not going to be used directly with your `number` index, but TS will actually convert it to a string under the hood:

> This is because when indexing with a number, JavaScript will actually convert that to a string before indexing into an object. That means that indexing with 100 (a number) is the same thing as indexing with "100" (a string)
>
> (from the TS handbook linked in the question)

So the compiler probably prepares the stage for index access calls like `foo["anything"]`, and it will not complain if the value of `foo` will contain an undeclared `anything` key.